# Golang привести дату к определенному виду

Tags: golang, время

К примеру есть:
var a = "03.04.2018"
Как привести ее к виду:
Tue Apr 03 2018 
Пробую так:

```
const layout = "Jan 2 2006"
t, _ := time.Parse(layout, "10.05.2006")
fmt.Println(t.Format(layout))
fmt.Println(t.UTC().Format(layout))
```

вывод:
Jan 1 0001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const layout = "2006.01.02"
const layout2 = "Jan 2 2006"
str := "2018.04.03"
t, err := time.Parse(layout, str)

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
fmt.Println(t.Format(layout2))
```